# Can I use "some" as a synonym of "very"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, some-any

I heard `some` used unusually a few times. Based on context, I figured that the meaning of `some` in that sentences was `very`.

However, I'm not sure. Can I really use `some` as a synonym of `very`?

Here are some examples, starting with `stuff`.

> This is some good stuff = this is very good stuff

With `work`:

> This is some good work = this is a very good work

With `news`:

> This is some good news = this is very good news

Comment: Note that you need to stress the word *some* if you want to use this meaning in speech. I think this means you can construct sentences which have three different meanings depending on three possible levels of stress on some. That's some interesting linguistics.

Comment: In Nova Scotia, Canada, there is (used to be) a spoken use of *some* that could mean *very* but more often meant *quite*.  One would hear 'It's some cold.' or perhaps (of a meal) 'It's some good.' and occasionally 'She was some mad.'.

Comment: "Some", in the appropriate context, is slang for "very".  In a strict non-slang sense the word "some", however, would be taken to mean kind of "mediocre", to the extent that it modified intensity at all.  In the above sentences there is not enough context to tell which.

Comment: You can, kind of, as some of the answers point out, but *none of your sentences are examples of that*.

Comment: @Icy is it possible that the expressions are reducing "some kind of" as in "she is some kind of mad."?

Comment: To expand on the comment by @hobbs: In all these examples, I would interpret 'some' as an adjective modifying the noun rather than as an adverb modifying 'good'.  It's a quantifier here, but an informal and ill-defined quantifier in the context.  As such I read it as a filler word that adds very little meaning & I suspect it was chosen to alter the cadence or as a colloquialism.

Comment: I disagree with @hobbs, all those sentences *could* be examples of what you're asking about. They might not be depending on how the sentence is pronounced, but they definitely could be.

Comment: In none of those examples would I equate "some" with "very". It wouldn't be unusual for someone to say "this is some very good work" - "very" is modifying the word "good", while "some" is defining a set (work/news/etc)

Answer (score 24):

If 'some' is the *only* modifier attached to a singular noun, it probably will be understood as an adjective meaning 'extraordinary' or 'remarkable', with an implied a/an. To me, this seems like the most obvious reading of the example in Cathy Gartaganis's answer, 'That's some woman!'

The exclamation mark confirms it further, because the other possibility is a disinterested 'That's some woman [or other].'

On the other hand, in the OP examples, without the emphasis of speech I think the focus is on the true ajective 'good'. 'Some' sounds like an expression of quantity in all three cases.

Comment: I almost downvoted this, but "without the emphasis of speech" saved it.

Answer (score 15):

Not really.  Some, as defined by the American Heritage dictionary 5th edition means "remarkable."  In the cases you've given, "some" means an unspecified amount.  In your sentence "This is some good stuff." it could be argued that "some" means remarkable (hard to know in print) but "some" cannot be exchanged with very because very would be intensifying or modifying "good" in a way that "some" doesn't.  "Some" isn't used to make "good" even better -- very does that job.

For example, "That's some boss you've got."  some means remarkable.  Very wouldn't work as it's usually used as an adverb or as an adjective, as in "the very best."

Comment: "'Some' isn't used to make 'good' even better -- very does that job." The entire province of Nova Scotia would disagree with you quite vehemently. And "some" can be intensified further by using "right some". It's regional and informal, but it's also proper in the dialects that use it.

Comment: I might interpret (depending on context) "That's some *boss* you've got" (with "boss" emphasised) as being any of the three "Your boss is terrible", "Your boss is remarkable", or "Your boss is really good looking"...

Comment: @cypher I don't understand your point.

Comment: @michael_timofeev nothing that makes "some" synonymous to "very", I'm just pointing out the meaning of "some" isn't necessarily restricted to "remarkable" in that sentence, or in many cases (and I might add if used as the last meaning it's just about cringeworthy :P).

Comment: @cypher ok...wasn't sure what you meant but now I understand.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it can be said in informal English.
It can replace 'a very nice': That's some woman!

A statement with 'some' might have clarification. In the case of a woman, you'd list her attributes. If you say, That's some fish! , you might be referring to the size or the taste, depending on the circumstances.

'some' can also have a negative connotation. Some friend you are! You never help!

Comment: Worth noting that referring to a woman in such a manner would probably be considered rude or at least uncouth/disrespectful. (I could see perhaps, "She's/You're some woman!" on the heels of some impressive act being a compliment, but I think there would still be risk of offense.)

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm Canadian, and I'd definitiely use it as a compliment, meaning an awesome woman in every respect.

Comment: This is some answer! (I mean that as a compliment.) Mostly, though, I liked the way you say that it can be used positively or negatively. Consider: _Her brother just got paroled for the third time. He is **some** brother!_ That's a put-down, but: _Her sister just graduated cum laude from Cal Tech. She's **some** sister!_ That's intended as a compliment, much in the way [Charlotte used the word](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e7/f0/8c/e7f08c3b6d95d859394848c6172d6e54.jpg).

Comment: Or, more famously, "That's some pig!"

Comment: However it isn't a synonym of `very`, as asked in the question. That would convert to: `That's very woman!"`

Comment: @NickGammon Correct, which is why I clarified that 'some' can replace 'a very nice'.

Answer (score 3):

You can, but I would definitely avoid it in written language.

In spoken language, depending on the inflection I use I could say:

"That is some good work" - to mean:

1. You've learned some new task well and I think you're ready to move on to learning the next thing.
2. Although some of what you did is good, most of it is unacceptable.
3. Wow, I'm really impressed.  That's very good.

Given that the inflection can't come across in writing, I'd avoid this since it could be interpreted as a compliment or an insult.

Comment: I think that only in sense 2 does "That is some good work" meaningfully differ from "That is good work".  I would expect this sentence used in sense 2 to be further qualifed, e.g. by immediately following with "but the rest needs to be redone."

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can be used interchangeably sometimes. Like here for instance:

> That is *some* shirt you got on!

or

> That is a *very* nice shirt you are wearing!

Comment: "That is *some* shirt" -> "That is a peculiar shirt".

Comment: Yep, "some shirt" would be taken by most to mean "unusual shirt".  Not necessarily a complement.

Comment: Your example compares "some" with "very *nice*", not with "very" by itself.  Although I agree that "some" might be taken as you describe under certain circumstances, that's not what the OP asked about.

Comment: @HotLicks - But it _could_ be a compliment. No way to say for sure, though, without hearing the intonation, and perhaps seeing the looks of envy.

Comment: @J.R. - My T-shirts don't usually elicit looks of envy.

Comment: @HotLicks - T-shirts? Probably not. But if you drove off the lot back to your driveway, and I said, "Wow! That's some car!" I probably wouldn't mean that it's unusual or peculiar.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but only when speaking because it requires that you emphasize the word "some". If you fail to emphasize the word "some" the additional meaning of "some very good" may be lost.

The principle is the use of an **understatement**, a form of irony where the words themselves deliberately do not convey the intensity of your meaning.

> This is SOME good work!

meaning "this is (some very good) work." (note that I have deleted the superfluous "a")

The same idiom exists in spanish:

> Un PEDAZO de trabajo!

Literally, "a piece of work", but with the correct emphasis, "a GREAT piece of work."

Answer (score 1):

*Some* can mean *some quantity of* or *some particular example of* or *some kind of*.

So "That's some cheese" can mean either "That's a quantity of cheese", or "that's a type of cheese" or "that's a special cheese". Context will tell you which.

- What's that in the fridge? That's some cheese.
- What's that smell? That's some cheese!

Or

- Knocking on the door? Some man.
- Climbing Everest with a teaspoon? Some man!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, if you use it in the (informal) expression ["...and then some"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/and-then-some), it can be used as an intensifier similar to "very", meaning "and plenty more than that".

```
This is good stuff, and then some! ≈ This is very good stuff!
This is good work, and then some! ≈ This is very good work!
This is good news, and then some! ≈ This is very good news!
```

I think all three are possible, although I personally would only be likely to use these in informal conversation where the context is clear.